# Adding Print, Data Extract functions to published Geoprocessing widget - ArcGIS 10.1 Viewer for Flex

Tags: arcgis-10.1, geoprocessing-service, arcgis-flex-viewer

I have developed a pretty detailed geo-processing widget (based on a model I built and published) that takes user input, runs raster calculator and then clips the raster output to a boundary. The tool works well and the results are displayed in Flexviewer 3.5.

While I'm happy with this I now want to expand the widget functionality and include additional functions such as data extract and print functionality.  I'm wondering what is the best way of achieving this? Do I need to build this into the original model or is there a way of merging the functionality of other widgets into my geo-processing widget?[image]